# How do I configure SonarCloud to detect and flag public methods and classes without any Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, static-analysis, sonarcloud

I want to use SonarCloud to flag code checked-in in the Pull Request if it does not have Javadoc added for public methods and classes. 
Unfortunately, I could not find much help online. Any help?

Comment: there is a checkstyle rule checking javadocs

Comment: @AdamSiemion Can you give more details?

I was able to activate the rule to include javadoc checks as Code Smells but when I check in code that does not contain javadoc, SonarCloud did not flag it in the analysis